# C++ game color needed

Tags: c++, colors, pacman

I Started making a Pacman style game with C++, All I want to do is give each thing a different color like player(o)Yellow Color, Enemy Ghost(@)red color, Fruit(.) or whatever you call it a blue color, Obstacles(#)brown color and plus sign(+) a green color
Hope you can help me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

char tmp_map[21][60];

char map[21][60] = {
"+#########################################+",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #", 
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"#                                         #",
"+#########################################+"
};

void ShowMap()
{
for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    printf("%s\n",map[i] );
}
}

void gotoxy( short x, short y )
{
HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) ;
COORD position = { x, y } ;

SetConsoleCursorPosition( hStdout, position ) ;
}

class entity {
public:
entity( int x, int y ){
    this ->x = x;
    this ->y = y;
}

void move_x( int p ){
    if( map[y][x+p] == ' ' ) x += p;
}

void move_y( int p ){
    if( map[y+p][x] == ' ' ) y += p;
}

void move( int p, int q ){
    x += p;
    y += q;
}

int get_x(){ return x; }
int get_y(){ return y; }

void draw( char p ){
    map[x][y] = p;
    gotoxy( x, y ); printf( "%c", p );
}

private:
int x;
int y;
};

struct walk {
long walk_count;
long x;
long y;
long back;
};

struct target {
long x;
long y;
};

vector<target> walk_queue;

vector<walk> BFSArray;

void AddArray( int x, int y, int wc , int back ){
if( tmp_map[y][x] == ' ' || tmp_map[y][x] == '.' ){
    tmp_map[y][x] = '#';
    walk tmp;
    tmp.x = x;
    tmp.y = y;
    tmp.walk_count = wc;
    tmp.back = back;
    BFSArray.push_back( tmp );
  }
  }

void FindPath( int sx, int sy, int x, int y ){
memcpy( tmp_map, map, sizeof(map) );
BFSArray.clear();
walk tmp;
tmp.x = sx;
tmp.y = sy;
tmp.walk_count = 0;
tmp.back = -1;
BFSArray.push_back( tmp );

int i = 0;
while( i < BFSArray.size() ){
    if( BFSArray[i].x == x && BFSArray[i].y == y ){
        walk_queue.clear();
        target tmp2;
        while( BFSArray[i].walk_count != 0 ){
            tmp2.x = BFSArray[i].x;
            tmp2.y = BFSArray[i].y;
            walk_queue.push_back( tmp2 );

            i = BFSArray[i].back;
        }

        break;
    }

    AddArray( BFSArray[i].x+1, BFSArray[i].y, BFSArray[i].walk_count+1, i );
    AddArray( BFSArray[i].x-1, BFSArray[i].y, BFSArray[i].walk_count+1, i );
    AddArray( BFSArray[i].x, BFSArray[i].y+1, BFSArray[i].walk_count+1, i );
    AddArray( BFSArray[i].x, BFSArray[i].y-1, BFSArray[i].walk_count+1, i );

    /*
        AddArray( BFSArray[i].x+1, BFSArray[i].y+1, BFSArray[i].walk_count+1, i );
        AddArray( BFSArray[i].x-1, BFSArray[i].y+1, BFSArray[i].walk_count+1, i );
        AddArray( BFSArray[i].x+1, BFSArray[i].y+1, BFSArray[i].walk_count+1, i );
        AddArray( BFSArray[i].x+1, BFSArray[i].y-1, BFSArray[i].walk_count+1, i );

        AddArray( BFSArray[i].x+1, BFSArray[i].y-1, BFSArray[i].walk_count+1, i );
        AddArray( BFSArray[i].x-1, BFSArray[i].y-1, BFSArray[i].walk_count+1, i );
        AddArray( BFSArray[i].x-1, BFSArray[i].y+1, BFSArray[i].walk_count+1, i );
        AddArray( BFSArray[i].x-1, BFSArray[i].y-1, BFSArray[i].walk_count+1, i );
    */
    i++;
}

BFSArray.clear();
}


int main()
{
bool running = true;
int x = 14; // hero column
int y = 16; // hero row
int old_x;
int old_y;
int a = 1000000000;
int ex = 4;//enemy column
int ey = 3;//enemy row
int pts = 0;

system("COLOR 07");
printf("Hello World\n\n");
printf("H -> Hard\nN -> Normal\nE -> Easy\n\nInput : ");

char diffi;
int speedmod = 3;

cin>>diffi;

if( diffi=='N'){speedmod=2;}if(diffi=='H'){speedmod=1;}if( diffi=='n')      {speedmod=2;}else if(diffi=='h'){speedmod=1;}

system("cls");
ShowMap();

gotoxy(x,y);cout<<"s";

int frame=0;

FindPath( ex,ey,x,y );

while( running ){
    gotoxy( x, y );printf(" ");

    old_x = x;
    old_y = y;

    if ( GetAsyncKeyState( VK_UP ) ){
        if( map[y-1][x] == '.' ){ y--; pts += 10; }else
        if( map[y-1][x] == ' ' ) y--;
        if( map[y-1][x] == '|' ) y--;
        if( map[y-1][x] == '_' ) y--;
    }
    if ( GetAsyncKeyState( VK_DOWN ) ){
        if( map[y+1][x] == '.' ){ y++; pts += 10; }else
        if( map[y+1][x] == ' ' ) y++;
        if( map[y+1][x] == '|' ) y++;
        if( map[y+1][x] == '_' ) y++;
    }
    if ( GetAsyncKeyState( VK_LEFT ) ){
        if( map[y][x-1] == '.' ){ x--; pts += 10; }else
        if( map[y][x-1] == ' ' ) x--;
        if( map[y][x-1] == '|' ) x--;
        if( map[y][x-1] == '_' ) x--;
    }
    if ( GetAsyncKeyState( VK_RIGHT ) ){
        if( map[y][x+1] == '.' ){ x++; pts += 10; }else
        if( map[y][x+1] == ' ' ) x++;
        if( map[y][x+1] == '|' ) x++;
        if( map[y][x+1] == '_' ) x++;
    }

    if( old_x != x || old_y != y ){
        FindPath( ex,ey,x,y );
    }

    gotoxy( x,y );printf("o");

    map[ey][ex] = '.';
    gotoxy( ex, ey );printf(".");

    if( frame%speedmod == 0 && walk_queue.size() != 0 ){
        ex = walk_queue.back().x;
        ey = walk_queue.back().y;
        walk_queue.pop_back();
    }
    gotoxy( ex, ey ); printf("@");

    if( ex == x && ey == y ){
        break;
    }


    gotoxy( 32, 18 );
    gotoxy( 45, 1 ); cout <<pts;
    Sleep( 100 );
    frame++;
}
if(pts < 1000000)
{
system("cls");
printf("You Lose and your points: %i",pts );
cin.get();
cin.get();
cin.get();
cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
else if(pts > 1000000)
{
    system("cls");
printf("You Won and your Points: %i",pts);
cin.get();
cin.get();
cin.get();
cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: The color of output text can be set with a call to [`textcolor`](http://code-reference.com/c/conio.h/textcolor). Please don't post whole programs--SO asks for minimal code examples in questions to save everyone time: it makes it easier for those answering to know what to do to help, and makes questions easier to search for those with similar problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found parts of this code on the internet, and parts of it I wrote myself. I made a class named Colour and overloaded the `operator<<`. The code is as below:

```
#ifndef COLOUR_H
#define COLOUR_H

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

inline void SetColour (WORD val) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), val);
}

class Colour {
    private:
        WORD val;
    public:
        Colour(WORD x) : val(x) { }
        void set() const { SetColour(val); }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &, const Colour &);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Colour &c) {
    c.set();
    return out;
}

static const Colour blue (1);
static const Colour green (2);
static const Colour cyan (3);
static const Colour red (4);
static const Colour purple (5);
static const Colour dyellow (6);
static const Colour dwhite (7);
static const Colour grey (8);
static const Colour bblue (9);
static const Colour bgreen (10);
static const Colour bcyan (11);
static const Colour bred (12);
static const Colour pink (13);
static const Colour yellow (14);
static const Colour white (15);

/*
 * 1: Blue
 * 2: Green
 * 3: Cyan
 * 4: Red
 * 5: Purple
 * 6: Yellow (Dark)
 * 7: Default white
 * 8: Gray/Grey
 * 9: Bright blue
 * 10: Brigth green
 * 11: Bright cyan
 * 12: Bright red
 * 13: Pink/Magenta
 * 14: Yellow
 * 15: Bright white 
 */

#endif
```

Now, if you want to change the colour of the output of your program, you just do the following:

```
std::cout << red << "This text is red\n";
std::cout << blue << "This text is blue";
```

Note that this would only work on Windows.